# How can I code Custom Bottom Navigator Bar in Flutter with painter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to code below design in my flutter app.But i don't know how to make middle icon overflow the container?
[image]

Thanks in Advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a package if your Custom Clipper is struggling

Check out this package, there lot feature you can build for custom bottom bar in easy way.

https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar

Comment: No problem brother

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CustomClipper` to create any shape you want. Clippers are what shapes such as RoundedRectangleBorder use, for a custom shape you'll have to create a custom clipper. There's lot's of [articles](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-custom-clipper-28c6d380fdd6) that'll explain how they work in detail.

There's also some [packages](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar) that do something similar. While I don't know one that does exactly what you're looking for, you might get a head start looking at their code.